# How can I have my array stop reading in characters when the enter key is pressed?

Tags: c++, strcmp

I am new to programming and I can't seem to figure out how to fix this problem. My assignment is very simple, to order two words alphabetically using only the strcmp function.

My program compiles and runs, but it doesn't progress until I fully fill the array with characters, but we are meant to be able to use words of different lengths.

Here is what I have written:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>
  using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int x;
        char wordone[10]  ,  wordtwo[10];

        cout << "Please enter your first word: \n";
        for(x=0; x<10; x++)  cin >> wordone[10];
        cout << "Please enter the second word: \n";
        for(x=0; x<10; x++)  cin >> wordtwo[10];

        if(strcmp(wordone, wordtwo)<0)
        {
        cout << wordone << endl << wordtwo;
        }
        if ( strcmp( wordone,wordtwo)>0)
        {
        cout << wordtwo << endl << wordone;
        }

        else
        {
        cout << wordone << endl << wordtwo;
        }


        return 0;
}


And the output looks like this:

Please enter your first word: 

help
me
please

Please enter the second word: 

hello
how
`
@
àu0þ
```

I've been trying every combination I can think of, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `std::getline` instead of `>>` streaming into a variable that isn't being checked for failure anyway.

Comment: Change `cin >> wordone[10]` to `cin >> wordone[x]` for the second input too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm trying this but it gives me this error : no matching function for call to âgetline(std::istream&, char&)â
  for(x=0; x<10; x++)  getline (cin, wordone[10]);

Comment: If I use wordone and wordtwo[x] the program runs but I'm still having the same problem, looks like this:                                                                                                                      Please enter your first word: 
hello
hello
Please enter the second word: 
help
hello
s
hellohello
helphellos@hellohello
helphellos@[

Answer (score 0):

For input. Use getline or directly take input.
 Instead of this -

```
 cout << "Please enter your first word: \n";
 for(x=0; x<10; x++)  cin >> wordone[10];
```

Possible solutions.

1. Do this -

   ```
   char name[10];
   cin>>name;
   ```
2. or do this

   ```
   string s;
   cin>>s; // simply take input like ordinary variable. Rember to #include<string>
   ```
3. or do this --

   ```
   string s;  // for getline this is must. Use string
   getline(cin,s);
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first solution and it worked exactly like I was looking for.

Comment: Good, but remember these too. Sometimes you can encounter a situation where they will be useful.